# CSS: How to remove a header on the first page of a chapter

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using CSS to convert HTML to PDF. I add page numbers to the bottom of the page and a name of the chapter to the top of the page (with @top-center, see the CSS and HTML code bellow). This works fine. Then I render PDF with [Prince](https://www.princexml.com).

I need to avoid printing the page header on the first page (because the heading is already there) and leave the page header only on the second and other pages.

Can you please advise, how to remove the header on the first page of the chapter and leave it on others?

```css
@page {
 margin: 27mm 16mm 27mm 16mm;
 size: 7in 9.25in;
}

div.chapter {
  page: chapter;
}

h1 {
  string-set: chapter content();
}

@page chapter:left {
  @top-center {
    font: 11pt "Bookerly", serif;
    content: string(chapter, first);
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
   color: #888888;
  }

  @bottom-center {
    font: 11pt "Bookerly", serif;
    content: counter(page);
    padding-top: 2em;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}

@page chapter:right {
  @top-center {
    font: 11pt "Bookerly", serif;
    content: string(chapter, first); 
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 2em; 
  font-variant: small-caps;
color: #888888;
  }

  @bottom-center {
    font: 11pt "Bookerly", serif;
    content: counter(page);
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Book</title>
 </head>

 <body lang="CS" vlink="purple" link="blue" class="calibre"> 
  <div class="chapter">

   <h1 id="c1">Heading</h1>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla est. Duis pulvinar. Aliquam ornare wisi eu metus. Mauris dictum facilisis augue. Nunc auctor. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Fusce wisi. Etiam ligula pede, sagittis quis, interdum ultricies, scelerisque eu. Curabitur ligula sapien, pulvinar a vestibulum quis, facilisis vel sapien. Duis condimentum augue id magna semper rutrum. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce tellus odio, dapibus id fermentum quis, suscipit id erat.</p>
   <p>Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Vivamus ac leo pretium faucibus. Donec quis nibh at felis congue commodo. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Curabitur bibendum justo non orci. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur ligula sapien, pulvinar a vestibulum quis, facilisis vel sapien. In convallis. Curabitur vitae diam non enim vestibulum interdum. In rutrum. Nulla non arcu lacinia neque faucibus fringilla. Vivamus ac leo pretium faucibus. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Donec ipsum massa, ullamcorper in, auctor et, scelerisque sed, est. Proin in tellus sit amet nibh dignissim sagittis.</p>
   <p>Maecenas aliquet accumsan leo. Duis condimentum augue id magna semper rutrum. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Duis bibendum, lectus ut viverra rhoncus, dolor nunc faucibus libero, eget facilisis enim ipsum id lacus. Etiam bibendum elit eget erat. Integer imperdiet lectus quis justo. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Duis viverra diam non justo. Etiam bibendum elit eget erat. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Suspendisse sagittis ultrices augue. In convallis. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Mauris metus. Aliquam ante. Nulla non arcu lacinia neque faucibus fringilla.</p>
   <p>In rutrum. Praesent in mauris eu tortor porttitor accumsan. Mauris elementum mauris vitae tortor. Morbi scelerisque luctus velit. Integer malesuada. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. Duis risus. Nam quis nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Aenean vel massa quis mauris vehicula lacinia. Maecenas fermentum, sem in pharetra pellentesque, velit turpis volutpat ante, in pharetra metus odio a lectus. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Mauris tincidunt sem sed arcu.</p>
   <p>Nulla quis diam. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. Maecenas lorem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Aenean fermentum risus id tortor. Cras elementum. Etiam bibendum elit eget erat. Suspendisse nisl. Praesent vitae arcu tempor neque lacinia pretium. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Etiam egestas wisi a erat. Aenean id metus id velit ullamcorper pulvinar. Pellentesque arcu. Pellentesque ipsum. Fusce tellus.</p>
   <p>Mauris elementum mauris vitae tortor. In dapibus augue non sapien. Nullam feugiat, turpis at pulvinar vulputate, erat libero tristique tellus, nec bibendum odio risus sit amet ante. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Praesent dapibus. Proin mattis lacinia justo. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Nunc auctor. Phasellus enim erat, vestibulum vel, aliquam a, posuere eu, velit. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Morbi leo mi, nonummy eget tristique non, rhoncus non leo. Ut tempus purus at lorem. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
   <p>Vestibulum erat nulla, ullamcorper nec, rutrum non, nonummy ac, erat. Mauris dolor felis, sagittis at, luctus sed, aliquam non, tellus. Sed elit dui, pellentesque a, faucibus vel, interdum nec, diam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce tellus. Quisque porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Fusce wisi. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Integer in sapien. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem.</p>
   <p>Mauris metus. Fusce tellus. Fusce aliquam vestibulum ipsum. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Maecenas sollicitudin. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean fermentum risus id tortor. Integer imperdiet lectus quis justo. Integer malesuada. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.</p>
   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Vestibulum fermentum tortor id mi. Nam sed tellus id magna elementum tincidunt. Cras pede libero, dapibus nec, pretium sit amet, tempor quis. Aliquam in lorem sit amet leo accumsan lacinia. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla quis diam.</p>
   <p>Suspendisse sagittis ultrices augue. Duis bibendum, lectus ut viverra rhoncus, dolor nunc faucibus libero, eget facilisis enim ipsum id lacus. Mauris elementum mauris vitae tortor. Mauris metus. Nulla pulvinar eleifend sem. In dapibus augue non sapien. Phasellus rhoncus. Cras elementum. Nullam faucibus mi quis velit. Pellentesque ipsum. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
   <p>Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Quisque tincidunt scelerisque libero. Curabitur sagittis hendrerit ante. Vestibulum fermentum tortor id mi. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Nullam dapibus fermentum ipsum. Duis pulvinar. Mauris elementum mauris vitae tortor. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Praesent vitae arcu tempor neque lacinia pretium. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Quisque tincidunt scelerisque libero. Etiam posuere lacus quis dolor. Praesent vitae arcu tempor neque lacinia pretium. Morbi leo mi, nonummy eget tristique non, rhoncus non leo. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero.</p>
   <p>In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Vestibulum erat nulla, ullamcorper nec, rutrum non, nonummy ac, erat. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Vestibulum fermentum tortor id mi. Etiam neque. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Nulla non arcu lacinia neque faucibus fringilla. Mauris elementum mauris vitae tortor. Integer tempor.</p>
   <p>Mauris tincidunt sem sed arcu. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Pellentesque ipsum. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl. In dapibus augue non sapien. Nullam at arcu a est sollicitudin euismod. Curabitur vitae diam non enim vestibulum interdum. Etiam posuere lacus quis dolor. Integer pellentesque quam vel velit. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Integer imperdiet lectus quis justo. Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Fusce tellus odio, dapibus id fermentum quis, suscipit id erat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Donec quis nibh at felis congue commodo. Fusce wisi.</p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following CSS code resolved the issue:

```css
@page chapter:first {
  @top-center {
    font: 11pt "Bookerly", serif;
    content: "";
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
   color: #888888;
  }

  @bottom-center {
    font: 11pt "Bookerly", serif;
    content: counter(page);
    padding-top: 2em;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```